# Error al modificar authentication middleware de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando modificar el middleware de Authentication de Laravel, al añadir el metodo handle para que si el usuario ha sido descativado haga logout, recibo el siguiente error:

> Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, $guard) should be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Authenticate extends Middleware {

    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request) {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && auth()->user()->active == 0) {
            Auth::guard()->logout();
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente estás usando código personalizado sacado de una versión de Laravel que no coincide con la de tu proyecto actual

El método `handle` ya no admite una cadena como tercer parámetro sino que es un número indeterminado de guardias (fíjate en los tres puntos `...` y el nombre del parámtro):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
```

Tendrás que reescribir la declaración de ese método y tener en cuenta en la implementación que te puede llegar más de una guardia